# Is it possible to create a unit test to test subclass of KeyListener?

Tags: java, unit-testing, keylistener

I am a student and currently trying to create unit test for a pacman game that can be controlled by keyboard. One of the classes that I am still trying to test is a class that inherits from **KeyListener**, and the reason is because I cannot find a way to test / call KeyPressed() function.
Is is possible to unit test KeyPressed() without any plugin (example: groovy) like stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998448/how-to-trigger-a-keypressed-event-for-unit-testing-in-java) here?

The game is written in Java, and I am testing using JUnit.
Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you saying you want to test if your KeyListener event handler is called?

Comment: I want to create a unit test for a class that inherits KeyListener. I don't know how to mock keyboard input as an input to my unit test, i.e, some functions like keyPressed() is called when a key is pressed. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you did that you'd be testing windows. To test your handler, just call the method. To test if your class has a handler check the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) is only an interface, you can test it by simply calling the method you want to test.  The one iffy part is the [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) that gets passed in.  That is a concrete class.  But there's a good chance that you can create your own by hand if you want (I'm basing this off the javadoc).

You're going to have to be more specific.  What do you want to test?  What do you consider a plugin?  Would [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) be a plugin?  That will make it very easy to create a `KeyEvent` for your needs.

But in general here's a better strategy: Put as little code as possible in the `KeyListener` implementation.  Only extract what you need from the `KeyEvent` and pass it into your class with game logic in it.  Now you don't even need to test the `KeyListener` anymore/much, you just test the method that it calls.

Comment: I think mockito is the answer. I want to mock an event, and see if my handler is being called and it gives the right function. Can mockito do that?

Comment: @blenzcoffee ah, so you want to trigger an event.  This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6843305/61624  Mockito would only help in creating the event.